# responsive images max-width property in newsletter email

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-email

I designed a responsive email with several elements, each one with a main image.

To prevent images breaks in iphone resolution and higher, I have:

```
img { max-width: 320px !important; height: auto !important; }
```

But then, images that are smaller than 320px scale to this width. I fixed that with:

```
img { max-width: 100% !important; width: auto !important; height: auto !important; }
```

This works for the main images, but then the business logo resizes to 100% of its parent container.

How I get the best of each solution?

Answer (score 1):

HTML coding for emails is a PAIN

See this chart: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ (you might have to scroll down the page, but it's there)

There is really little to no consistency between email clients as to what they will recognize. I would recommend just coding a simple page that 'squishes' nicely.

Answer (score 0):

First, your style will applied to all images, including your logo. Since you don't have specific class for images. Second, for email template you should use `inline styles` and using `table` for layouts. Example:

```
<table style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="main.jpg" style="width: auto; max-width: 100%">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <img src="logo.png">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```